# Downloading zip files in the browser and using their content in javascript

Tags: javascript, zip, babylonjs

For a 3D javascript game I am loading textures, 3D assets, music and additional javascript from the server.

Right now I am doing that by loading them individually, which takes around 30 seconds, so I would like to zip the files on the server and have the client download them, extract them and load them. How would I accomplish this, and the real question I have, how would I use these in Babylon calls that normally take urls?

Comment: you can unzip with with jszip http://stuk.github.io/jszip/ then you can loop the files and create a Blob() from each, and then use window.URL.createObjectURL(blob) to get a new url to use instead of the old http-based one.

Comment: @dandavis if you want some worthless internet points feel free to submit that as an answer and I will accept it